# A question on the category of sets

Tags: set-theory, category-theory

Why do SET, the category of sets and functions, is a locally small category? In other words, why do the collection of functions among two fixed sets is a set, and not a proper class?

Comment: $\mathsf{Set}$ is _not_ small. Your question indicates you mean it is _locally small_.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Sorry, i've edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the functions between two given sets $X$ and $Y$ is a subset of the powerset of the product $X\times Y$ (which is a set), being those pairs that satisfy a suitable property.